# Self Joining in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, tibble

Here is a sample tibble:

```
test <- tibble(a = c("dd1","dd2","dd3","dd4","dd5"), 
               name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
               b = c("dd3","dd4","dd1","dd5","dd2"))
```

And I want to add a new column b_name as self-join to test using:

```
dplyr::inner_join(test, test, by = c("a" = "b"))
```

My table is way to large (2.7M rows with 4 columns) and I get the following error:

> Error: std::bad_alloc

Please advise how to do it right / best practice.

My final goal is to get the following structure:

```
   a     name  b     b_name
   dd1   a     dd3   c
   dd2   b     dd4   d
   dd3   c     dd1   a
   dd4   d     dd5   e
   dd5   e     dd2   b
```

Comment: I'm not getting this error. I receive an extra column for `a` column though.

Comment: @yarnabrina sorry, I have just edited the question

Comment: Will this work for your long table?: `new_test <- test %>% 
  mutate(b_name = name[match(test$b,test$a)])`

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan worked like a charm, checking for compliance. Please add as an answer and explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is `fmatch` from `fastmatch`

```
library(fastmatch)
test$b_name <- with(test, name[fmatch(b, a)])
test$b_name
#[1] "c" "d" "a" "e" "b"
```

---

According to `?fmatch` description

> fmatch is a faster version of the built-in match() function.

Answer (score 1):

For that number of rows, I think `data.table` is probably going to give you a lot more speed. So here's a data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)
```

### Approach #1: self-join:

```
test[test, on = c(a = "b")]
# test[test, on = .(a == b)] ## identical
```

### Approach # 2: using data.table::merge:

```
merge(test, test, by.x = "a", by.y = "b")
```

Comment: Doesn't work...

>Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__, : Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Comment: _"Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again."_ It's not that it doesn't work, it is that you have a lot of duplicated values, that result in an enourmous data.frame. If you really need that pile of duplicated values, you can try `by = .EACHI`, but of course that may not work due to constrains in the physical size. Is it possible / reasonable to remove duplicated values?

Comment: Vitaly showed a very simple solution with match and it works. It should be a simple join but for some reason it doesn't work. What do you think?
Intersection between a and b is 3499 out of 3500 possible unique id's.

Comment: Please look on the df again, I have a id and b id from the same set of possible id's. One of them is named and I need to add names to others as there is a hierarchical relation.

Can you please advise how to work it out? @pavodive

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple solution using `match` function from `base` and `mutate` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

new_test <- test %>% 
  mutate(b_name = name[match(test$b,test$a)])
```

However, be careful with very long tables as `match` might not be the best implementation.